# Count how many times each word from a word list appears in a file?

Tags: bash, grep

I have a file, `list.txt` which contains a list of words. I want to check how many times each word appears in another file, `file1.txt`, then output the results. A simple output of all of the numbers sufficient, as I can manually add them to `list.txt` with a spreadsheet program, but if the script adds the numbers at the end of each line in `list.txt`, that is even better, e.g.:

```
bear 3
fish 15
```

I have tried this, but it does not work:

```
cat list.txt | grep -c file1.txt
```

Comment: You forgot to mention the input file format. One word per line? Can "words" have blank spaces in them? What about the data set in which to grep?

Comment: `list.txt1` is one word per line. One word can have some spaces. The data in `file1.txt` is many sentences, but a line never breaks across multiple lines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this in a loop that reads a single word at a time from a word-list file, and then counts the instances in a data file. For example:

```
while read; do
    echo -n "$REPLY "
    fgrep -ow "$REPLY" data.txt | wc -l
done < <(sort -u word_list.txt)
```

The "secret sauce" consists of:

1. using the implicit REPLY variable;
2. using process substitution to collect words from the word-list file; and
3. ensuring that you are grepping for whole words in the data file.

Comment: This will count the number of matching lines, not the actual occurrence count (if there are multiple matches on a line, it will only count as one). In theory, `fgrep -o -c` should fix this, but it didn't work correctly in some recent versions of GNU `coreutils`.

Comment: Great catch, @tripleee. That was an edge case I hadn't considered. I've updated the answer to address your use case.

Answer (score 4):

This awk method only has to pass through each file once:

```
awk '
  # read the words in list.txt
  NR == FNR {count[$1]=0; next}
  # process file1.txt
  {
    for (i=0; i<=NF; i++) 
      if ($i in count)
        count[$i]++
  }
  # output the results
  END {
    for (word in count)
      print word, count[word]
  }
' list.txt file1.txt
```

Comment: +1 for no sorting, a single pass through the input, no temporary file. If you want to preserve the order from `list.txt` in the output, it's easy to add an index in a second array to the `NR==FNR` case.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
tr -s ' ' '\n' file1.txt |
sort |
uniq -c |
sed -e '1i\s|.*|& 0|' -e 's/\s*\(\S*\)\s\(\S*\)\s*/s|\\<\2\\>.*|\2 \1|/' |
sed -f - list.txt
```

Explanation:

- Split `file1.txt` into words
- Sort the words
- Count the words
- Create a `sed` script to match the words (initially zero out each word)
- Run the above script against the `list.txt`

Answer (score 1):

single line command

```
cat file1.txt |tr " " "\n"|sort|uniq -c |sort -n -r -k 1 |grep -w -f list.txt
```

The last part of the command tells grep to read words to match from list (-f option) and then match whole words(-w) i.e. if list.txt contains contains car, grep should ignore carriage.

However keep in mind that your view of whole word and grep's view might differ. for eg. although car will not match with carriage, it will match with car-wash , notice that "-" will be considered for word boundary. grep takes anything except letters,numbers and underscores as word boundary. Which should not be a problem as this conforms to the accepted definition of a word in English language.